# Can't connect to rabbitmq - ACCESS_REFUSED

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

everyone!

I want to connect to rabbitmq with aio_pika using an admin level login and password.

```
async def send_rmq(message) -> None:
    connection = await connect("amqp://login:password@url")
```

An error occurs when connecting:

```
aiormq.exceptions.ProbableAuthenticationError: ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.
```

I tried connecting through the web interface and the curl command:

```
curl -s -u login:password http://url:15672/api/queues/%2F/name_queue | grep -o '"messages":[0-9]*'
```

I login to the interface and get the actual values of the number of curl command, that is, there is no problem with the network, as I understand.

What could be the problem?

I am working on a remote server, the project is running in the docker, Rabbit is running on another server, also in the docker.
Curl request I send from the terminal of the remote server where I work

Answer (score 1):

maybe use the ip-address and make sure the user is an administrator in RabbitMQ:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-spec.html, URI example with IP:

```
connection = await aio_pika.connect_robust(
    "amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1/",
)
```

And check that you can reach the remote server with for example tcn or other commands.

Check also in logs for RabbitMQ after code exception:

```
aiormq.exceptions.ProbableAuthenticationError: ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.
```

RabbitMQ Management->Overview->Nodes->Nodename = config and log files location.

Broker file (here is the reason):

```
 2023-07-23 15:02:48.432000+02:00 [error] <0.55597.0> PLAIN login refused: user 'admin' - invalid credentials
```

Update the password to a new password, it could be the issue.

Example
https://aio-pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick-start.html

Working result
https://github.com/spawnmarvel/test/blob/main/aio5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Just in case that could help someone: I experienced a very similar issue (using `Django`) in a specific environment and I finally found an explanation.

It turned out I was trying to use special characters in my RabbitMQ password which were incorrectly escaped and which are not be advised. It took me a while to figure out because I had repeatedly run a similar `curl` command and this command seemed to work fine. As a matter of fact, I was able to access RabbitMQ API because those special characters were interpreted, again.

In short, when you set a password, it is recommended to use an alphanumeric value with a very limited set of symbols (e.g. `:`, `=`). See RabbitMQ documentation: https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html#passwords-and-shell-escaping